# Propagation of GPLv3 licensed software

Tags: software, gpl, distribution-terms

"0. Definitions" section of GPLv3 says that:

> To “convey” a work means any kind of propagation that enables other parties to make or receive copies.

Is it also included to "any kind of propagation" if I transfer or share a link which directs people to download page of a software. I mean with the "download page" of software producer's download page. E.g. https://www.dillo.org/download.html